# How do I create a TableLayout that fills the parent and has rows with equal height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I want to create a `TableLayout` that fills it's parent where every row has equal height. What do I have to do to get rows with equal height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use layout_weight attribute for the TableRow elements in your layout. This will distribute the height equally (if you set your weights to be the same) over the parent height. First, set the parent `android:weightSum="1"` and then make sure all the weights of individual rows add up to `1`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <!-- Your columns here... -->  

    </TableRow>
<!-- Row 2 -->
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="5dp" >
     <!-- Your columns here... -->        
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I hope this helps. Please give it a try and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:  
 In your layout
 <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_cat_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subcat_headerlayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
      >
     </TableLayout>

  InActivity
  TableLayout SubCAtLyt = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.sub_cat_layout);

   View v1 = null;
        LinearLayout linear_pmain = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linear_pmain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LayoutInflater vii = (LayoutInflater)  getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
             tblRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
           arrBookDetails = db.Book( subCatid);
            int catAllLength = arrCatAllBookDetails.size();

           for (int j = 0; j < catAllLength; j++) {

          List<String> lBookDetails = arrBookDetails.get(j);
            //Row value layout
         String book = lBookDetails.get(10);
            v1 = vii.inflate(R.layout.sub_bottomthubnail, null);

                TextView txt = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtg1);
                txt.setText( book);
                txt.setTypeface(tface, Typeface.NORMAL);
                 tblRow.addView(v1, j);
    }
        SubCAtLyt.addView(tblRow);
```